# Designing WPF classes for DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have to build a chat app in WPF; I want to use DataBinding (still learning it) and want to do it in the right way. I've built a Buddy class in this way:

```
public class Buddy: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String _name;
    private String _status;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public String Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Status");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

I don't know which is the best way to handle BuddyList. Should I create a BuddyList class with Add and List method and then DataBinding to an instance of that class? What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`INotifyCollectionChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) to create your BuddyListClass
Look here for an example: [Usage of INotifyCollectionChanged](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/7b14a18f-2ed6-4713-b747-9defd05978dd/) 
Also you can use [`ObservableCollection<T>` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx#Y266).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to bind collections of items you should use the 
[ObservableCollection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

and another suggestions create and base class that implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
and derive from it each class that you want to bind to UI.

Answer (score 1):

I think your class definition looks just fine.

Regarding the list question I would expose my list as readonly for binding, and all the add, delete, edit functionality I would keep it private. To avoid informing manually your view for changes to your collection, I would use an `ObservableCollection` but exposing it to public as `ReadOnlyObservableCollection`.